# Can we get a red FAQ tag?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, meta

Web Applications launched before us as a beta, and they had a [red faq tag](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq).

Cooking launched after us as a beta, and they got a [red faq tag](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq).

In fact, Web Masters launched *alongside us* as a beta, and they started with a [red faq tag](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq)!

But ours, well, see for yourself: [faq](/questions/tagged/faq)

It hasn't really been problematic that it's a normal tag: in-site it's used pretty responsibly by everyone. But someone down the line is eventually going to point out the inconsistency with our site compared to others. And, well, I suppose that someone happens to be me.

I'm also a mite curious as to know why we didn't get a red tag in the first place, so if there is an explanation that would be neat. ♪

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure why this wasn't done, but it is fixed. (: