# Redirect tags to [tags]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

The following tags should redirect to [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) on Meta GSE, [tag](/questions/tagged/tag), [tagging](/questions/tagged/tagging), and [retagging](/questions/tagged/retagging).  This is how [MSO does it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/tags/synonyms), so no reason not to follow.

Answer (score 2):

I've merged [tagging](/questions/tagged/tagging) and [retagging](/questions/tagged/retagging), but I'm iffy about [tag](/questions/tagged/tag). Some questions are actually about the tags themselves ("[Can we get a red FAQ tag](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1451/can-we-get-a-red-faq-tag)" is not about tagging).

Comment: They're all ultimately about categorizing questions, with the action specified with other tags like [meta-tag:support] (for new ones), [meta-tag:discussion] (for application)