# [tag] redirects to [tagging] instead of [tags]

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

If [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) and [tagging](/questions/tagged/tagging) are going to be independent (not that I agree with that, [go comment here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/redirect-tags-to-tags)), [tag](/questions/tagged/tag) should at least stay pointed at [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) instead of [tagging](/questions/tagged/tagging).

Comment: I agree, all of them should be merged and synonyms.

Comment: If you see 'tag' as the verb 'to tag', rather than the noun 'a tag', you'll see 'tag' → 'tagging' actually can make sense.

Answer (score 2):

All three tags are now pointing to [tags](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tags).